# How to persist JobDataMap changes from remote client

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm working on a basic web client for Quartz.NET that among other things supports the modification of a job's JobDataMap at runtime.

My job is decorated with the following attributes which I believe is all that is necessary to make the job stateful:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class SampleTenantJob : IJob { ... }
```

At runtime, I execute the following code but the JobDataMap is not persisted:

```
    public void UpdateJobProperties(string jobName, string groupName, IDictionary<string, object> properties)
    {
        IJobDetail job;
        if (!TryGetJob(jobName, groupName, out job))
            return;

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (job.JobDataMap.ContainsKey(property.Key) && property.Value != null)
            {
                job.JobDataMap.Put(property.Key, property.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought initially this was because I was using the `XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin` for  jobs but I've tried both the in memory (RAMStore) and `AdoJobStore` and still can not persist `JobDataMap` changes made by the remote client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PersistJobDataAfterExecution (as the name implies) only applies when the job has finished executing, so the following job will track the number of times it is executed

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {           
        int count = (int?) context.MergedJobDataMap["Count"]    ?? 1;

        Console.WriteLine("hello " + count.ToString() );

        context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("Count" , ++count);    
    }
}
```

Without the PersistJobDataAfterExecution attributes, count is always the same.

Since you aren't running the job, this doesn't help you, and I think you have to delete and re-create the job with the new JobDataMap.

Of course, you aren't forced to use JobDataMap and can always to read and store information for your job from somewhere else.

Comment: "I think you have to delete and re-create the job with the new JobDataMap." - This is what I had to do, calling `scheduler.AddJob(job, replace: true);`